# Error: Too many characters in constant?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm learning C++, and I can't seem to work around this problem,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << “Hello World!” << endl;
system(“pause”);
return 0;
}
```

whenever I try to run it, I received these errors. Plus this is a answer given by my lecturer

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2015   too many characters in constant ConsoleApplication1
```

Comment: Don't use curly quotes, use straight quotes (the "inches" character, `"`). (I suspect you've copied this from a document written in a word processor which felt the urge to "correct" the code.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have Unicode quotation marks instead of ASCII quotation marks; probably your editor automatically changed them, or you copied the text from a site that does this automatically in its authoring software. Replace the quotes with normal ASCII quote (0x22, ") and it should work.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the wrong quotations characters. If I change what you have to:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I have no problems compiling (VC++2015).

It might be up to your keyboard settings which quotation characters are used.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the linker to 'No' to see if the error appears still